# Route change events while trying to avoid using $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-rootscope

As the [*Angular team*](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) (and severals [*blogs*](http://michaeleconroy.blogspot.fr/2013/09/dont-dirty-up-rootscope-create-global.html)) adviced, I try to avoid using `$rootScope` as possible in my apps.

> **`$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil**
>
> "Of course, global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly,
>   like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language.
>   In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to
>   put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a
>   service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily
>   tested." *- from [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)*

But in one of my apps, I use several times events such as `$routeChangeStart` that are **broadcast events** using `$rootScope`:

```
/* Force redirection to home page when a connected user calls login page */
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if(next.$$route.originalPath == '/login' && Session.isUserConnected()) {
        $location.path("/home");
    }
}
```

I don't see a way to avoid `$rootScope` in these cases.

- Is there a more elegant way to do this kind of tricks?
- Is that a design error of my app to use it?
- Must I resign myself to use it when absolutely necessary?

---

Tell me if you want me to provide more code samples.

Comment: Did you read this `global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly`???

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes, from the [first link](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) I provided (last paragraph). It is from the **Angular documentation FAQ**.

Comment: for this case you are just listening to an event broadcasted to $rootScope, I think this is a valid use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missread that. 
First of all, this event was added by Angular team - do you think they recommend not to use it?:D That article is about that you should not put everything to $rootScope, which seems to be an easy way for beginners.

Actually, using `$rootScope` - for for global events is absolutely ok -- that is actual purpose of this service.

Comment: I wonder if there are "good practices" about how to structure this code (as it in on $rootScope, you can write it everywhere) so that it remains as clear and as readable as possible

Comment: "global things that are always true", should be in app.run(). -- (cause it will always execute on your app init)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `$rootScope` in this scenario **yyou can achieve this this using the powerful `resolve`**.

Since I have seen you are using the `ngRoute` module, I created the Plunker and code for `ngRoute` resolve.I can create one for `ui-router` if you want it also.

**Using Resolve makes the code to execute faster since it will not undergo the DigestCycle**

You can get the user flag from the `Session.isUserConnected()` by injecting the session.

Then you can use that variable to redirect the route.

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('Test', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
     var user = true;
     //var user = Session.isUserConnected(); You can use your logic here
    $routeProvider
   .when("/login", {
        template: "Login View",
        resolve: {
           
         data: function($q, $timeout,$location) {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
              
              if (user) {
                $location.path("/home");
                deferred.reject();
              } else {
                deferred.resolve();
              }
            });
    
            return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    })
     .when("/home", {
        template: "Home View. It is redirected from Login by checking the user condition. Without using the rootscope",
      })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/login'});
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Test">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The main part goes here:

```
data: function($q, $timeout, $location) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() { 
        if (user) {
            $location.path("/home");
            deferred.reject();
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqV64f1rdjwzSMy13vgW?p=preview)

Comment: Interesting point of view. In terms of performance and design, is that better than using `$rootScope`? Do you think I **should** use it, or is that only a suggestion of "how to do differently"?

Comment: Since a change in `$rootScope` will run the digest cycle once again and resolve runs only once while a route is called, resolve may be better when compared to `$routeScope`, also, as you asked it is an alternative to `$rootScope`.

Comment: It does not *answer*, as I think it is still more complex and not sure better about performance. Anyway I upvoted your effort of showing another way to do this kind of things. :-)

Comment: Np, wait for few more answers and I will also search for otherways of doing it. :-)